# DynamoDB PHP update-item

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a simple small table which I just want to update. Spent hours in the docs and testing things out, can't figure it out.

My table:

```
|environment |who|
-------------------
|ax          |tom|
```

Primary key is on 'environment'

All I want to do is to set 'who' to 'ben' where 'environment' = 'ax'.

I have tried both the legacy way of doing things, and the expression way. I also tried both the square brackets notation AWS uses in their docs, and the array() notation of php. Below are some of the ways I've tried doing it.

1:

```
$result = $client->updateItem(array(
    'ConditionExpression' => 'environment = :env',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => array(
        ':env' => array(
            'S' => 'environment'
        ),
        ':who' => array(
            'S' => $who
        )
    ),
    'Key' => array( // REQUIRED
        ':env' => array(
            'S' => $env
        )
    ),
    'ReturnValues' => 'UPDATED_NEW',
    'TableName' => 'areas',
    'UpdateExpression' => 'SET who = :who'
));
```

2:

```
$result = $client->updateItem([
    'ConditionExpression' => 'environment = :env',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':env' => [
            'S' => 'environment'
        ],
        ':who' => [
            'S' => $who
        ]
    ],
    'Key' => [
        ':env' => [
            'S' => $env
        ]
    ],
    'ReturnValues' => 'UPDATED_NEW',
    'TableName' => 'areas',
    'UpdateExpression' => 'SET who = :who'
]);
```

3:

```
$result = $client->updateItem(array(
    'AttributeUpdates' => array(
        'who' => array(
            'Action' => 'PUT',
            'Value' => array(
                'S' => $who
            )
        )
    ),
    'Key' => array(
        'environment' => array(
            'S' => $env
        )
    ),
    'TableName' => 'areas'
));
```

**Edit:** This is the error I'm getting:

```
 SerializationException (client): Start of list found where not expected - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException","Message":"Start of list found where not expected"}'
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Your post reads like a statement, not a question. What is the exact issue?

Comment: @MarkB I have updated my post to now include the error message I get. I get the same error with each of the different ways I try to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had encountered a similar problem. This is the code that i used and it worked.

```
$RegID = "abracadabra";
$tableName="DefaultDelivery";
$marshaler = new Marshaler();

$requested_delivery = '{"Packet0":{"PacketNo":"2","Quantity":"1000ml","Type":"Toned Milk"},"Packet2":{"PacketNo":"4","Quantity":"250ml","Type":"Toned Milk"}}';

$eav = $marshaler->marshalJson('
{
 ":RequestedDelivery" : '.$requested_delivery.'
}
');

$key = $marshaler->marshalJson('                                               
     {                                                                          
         "RegistrationID" : "'.$RegID.'"
     }                                                                          
');

$params = [
     'TableName' => "$tableName",
     'Key' => $key,
     'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav,
     'UpdateExpression' => 'SET RequestedDelivery = :RequestedDelivery',
     'ReturnValues' => 'UPDATED_NEW'
];

try {
    $result = $client->updateItem($params);
        echo "SUCCESS";
}
catch (DynamoDbException $e){
   echo "Unable to update Item : \n";
}
```

Comment: I killed this project a while ago since it was a side project for work and it never got traction. I don't have the code anymore, nor the environment in which it ran. I am not sure if I am allowed to do this, but I will take your word for the solution and mark it as correct.